# Can't connect using PRO/Wireless 3945 ABG card with 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless

I can't connect to Wi-Fi in Ubuntu 12.04 with an Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG card. What can I do?

Every time I try to connect to a wireless router it keeps asking for a password and even though I write the password down it never fully connects, it just stops after a while and asks for the password again.

Comment: Give more information: what happens when you try to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the ubuntu forums to someone with the same problem and the solution that worked: [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121599)

Here is a copy/paste of the relevant answer:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ipwraw 
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945
sudo rm  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945.conf

Add a single line:
Code:
options iwl3945 swcrypto=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an XP machine. Try this:

1. In the device configuration settings Advanced tab, select the Ad Hoc QoS Mode and uncheck the "Use Default Value box". Select WMM Disabled from the drop down list.
2. On the Power Management tab, uncheck the box that says "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"

Hope this helps!